Print only first 5 articles in bibliography
Say I have a document with all my bibliographic references printed at the end, and stored in a .bib file with dozens of them.
I add this file with:
\addbibresource{references.bib}

And define the following \printbibsection command to print them:
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\printbibsection}[1]{%
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type={#1}, heading=none]%
    \end{refsection}
}%

Then inside the document:
\printbibsection{article} %I have other reference types

My question is: How can I just print the first 5 articles for example? I want to be able to do something like:
\printbibsection{article}[1-5]

Alternatively, is there a way to avoid that an article gets "cut" between pages? The reason why I want to print the first 5 only is because the next article gets "cut" (ie: the title in one page, and the journal, etc on the next).

Is your main objective to prevent a page break within a formatted bibliographic entry? Please confirm.

Yes, that would be the main goal, but it would also be good to know if it's possible to print specific references by number or range

Thanks for your reply and clarification. Please explain or motivate your use case some more. In particular, what is problematic or unfortunate about a formatted bibliographic entry that contains a page break? Is it mainly an aesthetic concern?

It is only aesthetics, it does not look good to have just the title on one page, and authors and journal on the next... I'd much rather include a page break there so the whole entry (title +authors+journal) starts at the top of the next page

I think the simplest solution is to hand-edit the .bbl file: Insert a \newpage instruction right before the entry that would otherwise experience a page break. Obviously, only do this at the very end of the process of creating your document.

Try adding \interlinepenalty=10000\relax after \begin{refsection}.
